# ASP.NET - How to write some html in the page? With Response.Write?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need that some html in the area in the asp.net page that i am coding, is changed according to a string variable.
I was thinking about creating a label, and then change the text on it.

But the string variable contains something like:

```
<h2><p>Notify:</p> alert</h2>
```

So, I don't feel that give this to a label text is a good idea

How i can do?
Using response.write?
If I use response.write, my added code will be at the beginning of the html source, how i can tell him to add it in a specific ?

Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

why don't you give **LiteralControl** a try?

```
 myLitCtrl.Text="<h2><p>Notify:</p> Alert</h2>";
```

Answer (score 39):

If you really don't want to use any server controls, you should put the `Response.Write` in the place you want the string to be written:

```
<body>
<% Response.Write(stringVariable); %>
</body>
```

A shorthand for this syntax is:

```
<body>
<%= stringVariable %>
</body>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, excellent. 
Can this be used to output JSON string?

Answer (score 10):

If you want something lighter than a Label or other ASP.NET-specific server control you can just use a standard HTML DIV or SPAN and with runat="server", e.g.:

Markup:

`<span runat="server" id="FooSpan"></span>`

Code:

`FooSpan.Text = "Foo";`

Comment: I can't see how "<span runat='server' />" is lighter than "<asp:Literal runat='server' />".

Comment: With VS2012 .net 4, it seems to be .InnerText and .InnerHTML.  Thanks, as this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Use a literal control and write your html like this:

```
literal1.text = "<h2><p>Notify:</p> alert</h2>";
```

Answer (score 4):

ASPX file:

```
<h2><p>Notify:</p> <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltNotify" /></h2>
```

ASPX.CS file:

```
ltNotify.Text = "Alert!";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use the **Literal** ASP.NET control for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the literal control of ASP.net or you can use panels or the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use pageMethods in asp.net. So that you can call javascript functions from asp.net functions. E.g.

```js
 [WebMethod]
    public static string showTxtbox(string name)
    {
         return showResult(name);
    }
      
    public static string showResult(string name)
    {
        Database databaseObj = new Database();
        DataTable dtObj = databaseObj.getMatches(name);

        string result = "<table  border='1' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2' >" +
                                            "<tr>" +
                                                "<td><b>Name</b></td>" +
                                                "<td><b>Company Name</b></td>" +
                                                "<td><b>Phone</b></td>"+
                                             "</tr>";

        for (int i = 0; i < dtObj.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            result += "<tr> <td><a href=\"javascript:link('" + dtObj.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim() + "','" +
             dtObj.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim() +"','"+dtObj.Rows[i][2]+ "');\">" + Convert.ToString(dtObj.Rows[i]["name"]) + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + Convert.ToString(dtObj.Rows[i]["customerCompany"]) + "</td>" +
                "<td>"+Convert.ToString(dtObj.Rows[i]["Phone"])+"</td>"+
             "</tr>";
        }

        result += "</table>";
        return result;
    }
```

Here above code is written in .aspx.cs page. Database is another class. In showResult() function I've called javascript's link() function. 
Result is displayed in the form of table.