# C# ASP.net File search

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have website developed in C# and ASP.Net 
I am trying to enable the search functionality in it by using a text box for the user to enter the file name and search for it. i got the logic to get the file names that matches the string entered by the user. Now, i am stuck on how to display the files in the .aspx page. I have to display the file name with href link to download it. the files are generally pdf, ppt, chm etc..
I have no clue on how to proceed further in this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are saying you don't know how to display data in the web page?

Comment: Yes. How to display with an href link.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET - How to write some html in the page? With Response.Write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969414/asp-net-how-to-write-some-html-in-the-page-with-response-write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be searching directories for files, that may reduce your site's performance and user's searches will not be reasonably accurate.

To apply that, create a table that has, for example, **FileName**, **FileLocation**, **FileType**, **Keywords**.. etc, and then create a page to upload these files and saves file's information in that table, this way will improve your search and it will save your application from possible performance and security issues.

But if you insists to keep doing your approach, I think your solution would have a list of files names from a specific directory that you have searched in, and I suppose you have a panel in your ASPX page:

**.ASPX page**

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

**.ASPX.cs page**

```
public void ListFiles(List<string> mfiles)
{
   for(int i=0; i < mfiles.length; i++)
   {
      Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href=\"/Files/" + mfiles[i] + "\">" + mfiles[i] + "</a>" ));
      Panel1.Controls.Add("<br />");
   }
}
```